# Best way to compare two generic values?

Tags: c#, generics, operator-overloading, comparator, icomparable

I'm writing a small class which I'm gonna move around when needed like a dll, and it's gonna have different sorting algorithms in it. I want the functions to work with any lists, of any types, including objects. So it's basically like this:

```
class TemplateSortings<T>
{
    List<T> GNRList;

    static void SortBubble<T>()
    {
        //Do stuff with GNRList, which can be a list of any values (nums, strings, objects)
    }
}
```

Now the question I'm having troubles with is this - what is the best way to compare two generic values: overloading comparison operators or having the class inherit IComparable interface? What is better and why?

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to work with any type, you probably shouldn't constrain `T` to types that implement `IComparable`, because not all types do.

A simple way to work around this is to let the caller decide how to compare the objects. You just need an extra parameter:

```
static void SortBubble(Func<T, T, int> comparator)
{
    ...
}
```

You can call `comparator` with 2 arguments and it will give you a negative value, 0, or a positive value indicating that the first parameter is less than, equal to, or greater than the second parameter.

As an example, you can call `SortBubble` with `int`s like this:

```
var sorting = new TemplateSortings<int>();
// populate the list...
sorting.SortBubble((x, y) => x.CompareTo(y)) // pass a lambda
```

EDIT:

If you don't want an extra parameter and want to check the type inside the method, you can do something like this:

```
if (typeof(IComparable<T>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))) {
    // do your sorting
    // you need to cast values of type "T" to "Comparable<T>" like this
    // var castedValue = (IComparable<T>)tValue;
} else {
    throw ...
}
```

Comment: It's a little bit uneffective, don't you think? I might now know what variables I'll use, so I was thinking of just passing down the list to sort to GNRList and then sorting it. I wouldn't know what type it will be...

Comment: That makes no sense. You have to tell it _how_ you want to sort the items, or else how would the computer know? @Alucard

Comment: I wanted the function themselves to check the type of the list. What if I have to work with decimals, or strings? Will I have to write another SortBubble function, but this time with <T, T, string>? Or can I just check the type inside the function? @Sweeper

Comment: What if you pass in something that's not comparable? @Alucard

Comment: Like what? I'll most likely know if it's uncomparable. I can always throw an exception or write my own function for comparison. In case of objects... I haven't given it much thought, but I'd probably sort them by one of the variables, like ID or some other value in another function, or I'd pass down a List made of those aforementioned variables? Maybe. @Sweeper

Answer (score 0):

You could generalize your code so it can work with any potentially valid type `T`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> BubbleSort(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    IComparer<T> comparer == null)
{
    var currentComparer = comparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default;
    //bubble sort with currentComparator 
}
```

Now, you can sort any `T` whatsoever, if:

1. `T` implements `IComparable<T>`
2. `T` implements legacy `IComparable`
3. You hand down a `Comparator` that knows how to compare `T`s

It will fail on any other scenario the moment you attempt to perform the first comparison.